# Updating Angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular7, angular8

I have a sample project that uses Angular 7. I am trying updating it to the version 8 using the following command:
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
which does absolutely nothing. The screen is not changing for a long time.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Actually after a very, very ling time it did produce the results.